# Возможности структур данных

Tags: списки, очередь, динамические-массивы, структуры-данных

Двусторонняя очередь реализуются на основе динамического массива или двусвязанного списка? 
Имеется ли в двусторонней очереди прямой доступ к произвольному элементу как в массиве? 
Какие структуры данных позволяют вставлять элемент в произволую часть? Я так понимаю динамические массивы, двусторонние очереди и списки позволяют вставлять элемент в "середину". Но втавка и удалении в произвольной позиции в списке выполняется быстрее чем в динамическом массиве или двусторонней очереди.

Answer (score 1):

Двусторонняя очередь может быть реализована и с помощью динамического массива или двусвязанного списка.

Произвольный доступ к элементу. У двух сторонней очереди такого доступа нет. Если она релизована через массив, то такую возможность добавить можно, но будет ли это уже просто очередью?

Элемент в "середину" позволяют вставлять все перечисленные вами структуры данных.

Думаю сложность вставки в списке и двусторонней очереди можно считать одинаковой. В динамическом массиве будет происходить копирование элементов после "середины" на позицию вперед.

Comment: @foreblack, только учтите, что ее можно  реализовать как кольцо в динамическом массиве. Тогда при операциях добавления в хвост и изымании головы ничего двигать не надо (пока (если) хватает уже выделенного места)

Comment: @pavelip если у двусторонней очереди будет произвольный доступ к элементом, то что это будет?